# conditional in HTML AngularJS

Tags: html, angular, conditional-statements

i have a little problem in my code, i work with angular and HTML, and when my "a> 0" my line becomes clickable and calls a function, and if my "a = 0" I have to display non clickable, knowing that my "a" is already recovered, I tried with a ng-if but I think I do not have the right syntax

I speak French, this message is translated by Google translation, I'm sorry if I made errers

what should I display when a> 0

```
          <tr height="25"
                name="a"  
                ng-click="startSearch(row,name)" 
                style="cursor: pointer">
                <td><a class="texte">a</a></td>
                <td align="right">{{a}}</td>
            </tr>
```

when a=0

```
            <tr height="25">
                  <td>a</td>
                  <td align="right">{{a}}</td>
            </tr>
```

what I try to do:

```
                  <tr height="25"
                   name="a"   
                   ng-click="startSearch(row,name)"
                   style="cursor: pointer"
                   ng-if="a > 0">
                  <td><a>a</a></td>
                  <td align="right">{{a}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="25"
                  ng-if="a= 0">
                  <td>a</td>
                  <td align="right">{{a}}</td>
                  </tr>
```

I know it's not much, I'll just like to understand my mistake, thanks

Comment: I am not able to understand your question exactly but one issue is that in condition you are using `ng-if="a= 0"` it should be `ng-if="a==0"`.

`=` is assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

Also I'm not sure that you need two ng-if there. You can use `ng-class`, `ng-style` (but as for me use `ng-class` will be preferable).
Wrote small example, hope that is what you expected.

```
<tr height="25" name="a" ng-click="startSearch(row,name)" ng-style="a>0 && {'cursor':'pointer'}">
  <td>
    <a ng-class="{'texte': a>0}">a</a>
  </td>
  <td align="right">{{a}}</td>
</tr>

<script>
  var startSearch = function (row, name, a) { //or try with ng-disabled instead 
    if (a <= 0)
      return;
      ...
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in this line: `ng-if="a= 0"`, Actually we use **=** to affect a value to a variable and **==** to check the equality.

So this line should be `ng-if="a == 0"`